# Can JavaScript reference an image source outside of the current folder?

Tags: javascript

I built a simple slideshow in which the picture changes every 7 seconds but if I move the page source outside of the folder with the image files it doesn't work.

It must be JavaScript rather than HTML related because the first picture loads fine, but once JavaScript attempts to change the image source I get a "file not found error".

Even when I tried making the 2nd image source the same file as the 1st image (which loads fine), I get the file not found message 7 seconds into loading the page (when JavaScript changes the source for the first time).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var image_tracker = 1

        function change(){
            var image = document.getElementById("gc");

            if(image_tracker==1)
            {
                image.src="C:\Users\Documents\IMG_1267.jpg";
                image_tracker = 2;
            }
            else if(image_tracker==2)
            {
                image.src="C:\Users\Documents\IMG_1239.jpg";
                image_tracker = 3;
            }
            else 
            {
                image.src="C:\Users\Documents\IMG_1263.jpg";
                image_tracker =1;
            }
        }
        timer = setInterval('change()',7000);
  </script>
</head>

<body>

    <img src="C:\Users\Documents\IMG_1263.jpg" height="512" width="688" id="gc" onclick="clearInterval(timer);">

</body>
```

Comment: Links to your local computer, for security reasons, won't work.

Comment: Did you try with `<img src="file:///C:\Users\Documents\IMG_1263.jpg" />`

Comment: You can actually do it. Only thing is that you can't use an absolute path to the filesystem( obviously for security reasons). You have to rely on relative paths and configure your web server to map to multiple folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back folders in your code using "..\" and i believe "~\"  to go back to the root of your project.
For example if i have the following folder structure:

- c:\website
- c:\website\images
- c:\website\images\1.png
- c:\website\images\2.png
- c:\website\images\3.png
- c:\website\scripts\

you could do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Var image_tracker = 1

        function change() {
            var image = document.getElementById("gc");

            if (image_tracker == 1) {
                image.src = "..\images\1.png";
                image_tracker = 2;
            } else if (image_tracker == 2) {
                image.src = "..\images\2.png";
                image_tracker = 3;
            } else {
                image.src = "..\images\3.png";
                image_tracker = 1;
            }
        }
        timer = setInterval('change()', 7000);
    </script>
</head>

<Body>
    <img src="..\images\1.jpg" height="512" width="688" id="gc" onclick="clearInterval(timer);">
</Body>
```

Comment: Does each "." go back one folder?

Comment: each ..\ goes back one folder. so if you want to go back 2 folders you do ..\..\